# How can I transform a file to bits?

Tags: python, binary

So I need to transform a file to bits and manipulate them 4 by 4. I'm currently starting in Python so I don't know how to do this. I currently have:

```
    fbi=open(route, "rb")
    fbi=fbi.read()
    print(fbi)
```

And I get something alike to hex values, except for some times, where I get things like " x0f|U+] " or "xd0F" and "x83*".

Can someone really explain to me how to get the bits, and also what I'm seing when I print fbi ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, clarify, which version of Python (is it 3.x?), and also what do you mean by "4 by 4": 2 bytes in sequence or are you operating at half-bytes?

Comment: When you print(fbi) you get the characters printed and what you see depends on your console settings, such as encoding.

Comment: I'm running python 3.x (Pyzo 2015a) and I'm going to operate at half-bytes yes. So how could I operate on the bits, and see them as 0 and 1?

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford the file contents to be read into memory all at once, then the simplest code is probably:

```
with open(p, "rb") as f:
    for b in f.read():
        print(b & 0xf) // least significant bits
        print(b >> 4) // most significant bits
```

If the files can be big, you'll need to complicate the code with an outer loop and a size argument to `read`.